# bash shell modes? how to pipe request to shell on remote server

Tags: shell, terminal, tty, node.js

I have this tcp server in Node.js that will open a shell and pipe the request to the shell:

```
const net = require('net');
const cp = require('child_process');

const server = net.createServer(s => {

  const bash = cp.spawn('bash');
  s.pipe(bash.stdin, {end:false});
  bash.stdout.pipe(s);
  bash.stderr.pipe(s);


});


server.listen('4004');
```

I connect to it with netcat like this:

```
nc localhost 4004
```

when bash opens up, I just get this kinda stuff (literal):

```
pwd
/app

ls -a
.
..
Dockerfile
main.js
run.sh


^[[B^[[A
```

Tab completion doesn't work and when I hit the up arrow key - I get the `^[[B^[[A1` chars - so I am thinking that bash has two modes or something - writing to stdout and waiting for stdin...because in bash normally when I hit the up/down arrow keys it will output previous commands unless a command is currently writing to stdout then I will get that garbolly-gunk output.

Does anyone know how to re-create a good shell experience on a remote server?   My code above "works" but it's not a real terminal, just a bash process or somethin.

Comment: If you want to recreate a good shell experience in your remote server, the best option is usually to use `ssh`, the "secure shell" program, to actually open one.  You seem to be spawning `bash` and hooking a standard input and output to it, but not a _terminal_, and `bash` can tell if it's an interactive terminal or not; if not it does not use `readline` to handle its input, which is (in part) what provides tab-completion, history, and so forth.

Comment: I see, so how could I tell bash that it's a TTY? that's an interactive terminal right?

Comment: If you want to write a Node program to emulate `rsh` (remote shell, without encryption), such a question would be more suitable for [so].